# Is there a JavaScript version of Reflection::newInstaceArgs(args)?

Tags: javascript, reflection, arguments

In JavaScript I have a string with a function name and an object with a list of arguments. Is there a way that I can call that function and pass the arguments to it?

For example, in PHP I can do the following:

```
$class = "myClass";
$args = array(arguments to be passed....);
$refClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
$instance = $refClass->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

I know that's a class, but is there something similar in JavaScript to call a function and pass the arguments in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you have to retrieve a handle (reference) to the function.

This is only possible in two cases:

- your function lives in the global context
- your function/its reference is assigned to a variable or to an object's property

After that, you can use the [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function:

```
functionReference.apply(window, args);
```

Here's a full sample for a global function:

```
function func1(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}

var funcName = 'func1';
var args = ["Hello World!"];

window[funcName].apply(null, args);
```

Comment: It does indeed live in the global context, thank you. I will give that a try. I am already using `window[funcName]();` Didn't realise it would be so simple applying the arguments.

Comment: This works great, the only note is it will only work with an array of arguments, not an object of arguments. I had to convert my object to an array first to get it to work. Minor detail.

Comment: You could use the .call function, if you don't want to use the array.  `window[funcName].call(window, arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: @Styphon I don't know from where you're getting these array-like objects, but try to avoid them if it's in your code.

Comment: @ComFreek - From an Ajax response. Can't avoid it.